# Easiest way to cross-reference a CSV file with a text file for common strings

Tags: regex, string, excel, csv, cross-reference

I have a list of strings in a CSV file, and another text file that I would like to search for these strings. The CSV file has just the strings that I am interested in, but the text file has a bunch of other text interspersed among the strings of interest (the strings I am interested in are ID numbers for a database of proteins). What would the easiest way of going about this be? I want to check the text file for the presence of every string in the CSV file. I am working in a research lab at a top university, so you would be aiding cutting-edge research!

Thanks :)

Comment: The easiest way might be able to use some kind of interactive RegEx tool and use that. Perhaps you could add RegEx to your tags and someone in there can help you - they love this stuff.

Comment: Some sample data might be useful. In which column within the CSV file are the strings you're searching for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Python for this. To print the matching lines, you could do this:

```
import csv
with open("strings.csv") as csvfile: 
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    searchstrings = {row[0] for row in reader}   # Construct a set of keywords
with open("text.txt") as txtfile:
    for number, line in enumerate(txtfile):
        for needle in searchstrings:
            if needle in line: 
                print("Line {0}: {1}".format(number, line.strip()))
                break   # only necessary if there are several matches per line
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, and sorry for taking so long to get back to you. This is probably a dumb question, but what argument should I put in place of infile, and should I put any arguments in txtfile.read()?

Comment: @maximum411: Whoops, that should have been `csvfile`. Corrected. And no, no arguments to `txtfile.read()` - we want the entire file to be read into a single string.

Comment: One more question- it would be nice if whenever I got a match between the CSV file and the text file, the script printed the rest of the text that is on the same line as the matching string in the text file, since the string I am searching for specifies a protein ID while the rest of the line in the text file includes information like name, function, etc. Do you have any ideas about how I should do this?

Comment: @maximum411: I have included a suggestion for this. This is a brute-force solution, which is likely to be OK for smaller files/number of searchstrings, but will get bogged down a lot with larger files in comparison to the other version. Optimization possibilities depend on the structure/contents of your data.

Comment: Great! It seems to be pulling the lines out just like I wanted. The one problem is that each printed line repeats many times, while there aren't any such repeats in the original data. Do you have any idea what could be causing this? Thanks again!

Comment: It prints the line once for each match. So if there are several matches per line, this will happen. Just add a `break` statement after the `print` (within the `if` block).

Comment: Interesting... there don't appear to be repeat matches in the line, but adding the break fixed it anyway. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Ah- never mind. Just as you said, there were repeats (in the CSV file, not in the text file). That makes sense now.

Comment: @maximum411: I have an even better idea that I should have used from the beginning: Use a `set` instead of a `list` for the `searchstrings`. Set lookup is `O(0)` instead of `O(n)`, and duplicates are removed automatically in a `set`.