# Cross reference a text file with an excel file -

Tags: string, excel, scripting, cross-reference

I have a text file with a list of usernames, and I have an excel file with about 4000 rows and about 9 columns. Basically what I'm looking to do is find any instance of anything from the TXT file in the Excel file. The match might not be EXACTLY the same, like :

TXT file has a row `monkey1`
excel file has a cell in column "C" with `\\server1\monkey1`

I would like to somehow flag that cell, or even the line in the TEXT file, or a seperate output.

I'm also pretty flexible on how to do this, like VBA/Macros etc. Or even putting this into an Access database or something similar. Or even converting the TXT to CSV or the Excel to another format.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, or any guidance on what I should be looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you open to using python?

Comment: I am open to use Python, but I'm somewhat new to it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Export as csv
2. Write a python script that reads the csv with the `csv` module;
3. and the text file;
4. and then appends a magic string, like `!!` to each cell containing the text of a line from the text file;
5. then outputs a csv file with the updated table;
6. Then you can import it in excel;
7. And format-search-and-replace `!!` into a formatting of background color.

Comment: I was able to find something similar to what you're describing here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139915/easiest-way-to-cross-reference-a-csv-file-with-a-text-file-for-common-strings/16140259#16140259

Comment: But I'm not really sure how to modify it to switch it to my needs, the code is pretty readable though, any hints ?

Comment: `import csv
with open("mdcnas100.txt") as txtfile:
 reader = txt.reader(txtfile)
 searchstrings = {row[0] for row in reader}   # Construct a set of keywords
with open("1.csv") as csvfile:
    for number, line in enumerate(csvfile):
        for needle in searchstrings:
            if needle in line: 
                print("Line {0}: {1}".format(number, line.strip()))
                break   # only necessary if there are several matches per line

Comment: @JasonGilmore: you can edit the row and use `csv.writer` to save the amended spreadsheet.