# Creating a new list when a condition is met with a value pair and a list

Tags: python, csv

Very first question ever on here. I have tried to find a solution for about a week now but I'm finally down to having to ask. I'm open to suggestions for the title of this question also.

I'm using python3

I have a csv file (legend.csv) that contains 2 headers(keys), one for numbers and one for abbreviations.

Each abbr has a corresponding number and this is represented in the csv file.

I also have a list of names (list.txt), the first part of the names are usually an abbr of some sort.

The idea behind the program is: I want to analyze the csv file and add the number that corresponds to the abbr in the names from the list.txt. The output should be a new text file if possible.

```
example of list.txt:
    addg-stuff
    cbdd-stuff
    abc-stuff
    add-stuff

example of legend.csv:
    number,abbr
    0001,addg
    0002,cbdd
    0003,abc
    0004,add


example of desired output:
    0003-abc-stuff
    0001-addg-stuff
    0004-add-stuff
    0002-cbdd-stuff
```

the following finds the abbr but I'm stuck on how to add the corresponding number to the name.
[Easiest way to cross-reference a CSV file with a text file for common strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139915/easiest-way-to-cross-reference-a-csv-file-with-a-text-file-for-common-strings)

The link above is where I found how to pull the matching strings but not sure where to go from here.

```
   import csv
   with open("legend.csv") as csvfile:
       reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
       searchstring = {row[1] for row in reader}
       num = {row[0] for row in reader}
   with open("list.txt") as txtfile:
       for names in txtfile:
           for i in searchstrings:
               if i in name:
                   matching = (name) #not sure where to go from here. If matching is printed, the names are found that contain the abbr.
```

Definitely new to this, just started messing with python for a month or so.
Any help would be much appreciated, especially if you have any good resources for situations like this or python in general.

Comment: Please post a sample from each file and the desired output for the sample.

Comment: I edited the post so you could see the examples you asked for.

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import csv

f1 = open('legend.csv')
f1 = csv.reader(f1) #splitting at instances of commas
f1 = list(f1) 

f2 = open('list.txt').read().splitlines() #reading every line in the txt file

for i in f2:
   for b in f1[1:]:
       if i.split("-")[0] == b[1]:
          print str(b[0])+"-"+i
```

Output:

```
0001-addg-stuff
0002-cbdd-stuff
0003-abc-stuff
0004-add-stuff
```

In the double for-loop, the algorithm takes a line from the txt file and then a line from the csv file. Note that the `f1[1:]` is list slicing. That means that we start after the header in the csv file, which for us is not helpful in solving the problem. From there, the algorithm tries to determine if the abbreviation is contained in the first part of the line, in this case stored as `i`. If so, the number and line are printed in the style of the of your desired output.

Comment: This is getting me close and will definitely help. Kind of hard to understand what is going on here though. Could you explain a little...

Comment: @cdub Please see my recent edit. Please let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The only thing I see that is a problem is that the abbreviations can create a duplicate results. I didn't specify this earlier but for each abbreviation their is a (-) before the rest of the name in the txt file. Can that character be used to get the whole abbreviation from the name. Hopefully cutting down on duplicates. Example: addg-stuff.  Sorry for not including that.